# How to change color of section and avoid setSectionPaint error/warn message

Tags: jfreechart

```java
  final PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    plot.setSectionPaint(i, color[i]);
    plot.setSectionPaint(plot.getSectionKey(i), color[i]);
  }
```

I try to set some other color to the section of a PieChart.

`setSectionPaint(int, Color)` method is deprecated

`setSectionPaint(Comparable, Color)` method : I cannot get a Comparable object because [`plot.getSectionKey(int index )`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html#getSectionKey%28int%29) is protected.

Is there a solution so I can change color of sections without error/warn message ?
Or how to retrieve the comparable object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the correct `Comparable key` from your data set to invoke the desired implementation of [`setSectionPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html#setSectionPaint%28java.lang.Comparable,%20java.awt.Paint%29). For example, in [`org.jfree.chart.demo.PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html), the following would set section `One` to `Color.black`.

```
plot.setSectionPaint("One", Color.black);
```

Comment: I had already realized that setSectionPaint need a `Comparable key` but the only one method that can give this Comparable key is protected so how to retrieve this key dynamically ? Do I have to write it and so I cannot put it in a `for` loop.

Comment: The keys are in your (unseen) data set; you can loop on whatever `Iterable` you choose to export.